# File caching creates problems when big folders are transferred

Tags: xubuntu, samba, rsync, cache

All the systems that experience problems during big folder transfers are running **Xubuntu 22.04.4**. One is using Kernel *6.5.0-26-generic* and is equipped with 16 GB of RAM and two are using Kernel *5.15.0-101-generic* and are equipped with 4 GB of RAM.

I attempted to copy a huge folder from an external USB drive to the internal drive on the 16 GB system using `thunar` and when the transfer reached approximately 10%, the transfer speed dropped dramatically and I was forced to cancel it since nothing was practically being transferred any more. It took quite a long time for the system to actually cancel the transfer. I had to split the transfer to many smaller chunks in order to complete all of it successfully. After that, nothing was working normally. The ***Applications menu*** was taking too long to appear, apps were taking too long to start, etc. I had to reboot that system for things to go back to normal.

The other two systems exhibit similar problems when receiving big folders through `samba`. The folders are copied correctly but everything else takes forever to start afterwards on them. Every big copy uses all their available memory.

Can `nocache` actually do something about this problem? If it can, can it be used in conjunction with `rsync`?

How can we solve the problem on the two 4 GB systems that act as file and folder receivers through `samba` and `nocache` cannot be used on them since the *copy* command is given on the file/folder sending system.

Thank you.